# Different Array Values depending on the if statement

Tags: php

I am building a web crawler which scans links, titles and meta descriptions from links that are found from one url submitted

This if statement i think is correct. $description is the variable which holds all the descriptions from the array $link. But i notice not all sites have a meta description (wikipedia for example) so i have decided that i would like the first twenty characters to act as the description if the description is empty. (By the way, the function and calling of everything works, i just wanted you to see it)

```
     if ($description == '') {
    $html = file_get_contents($link);    
    preg_match('%(<p[^>]*>.*?</p>)%i', $html, $re);
    $res = get_custom_excerpt($re[1]);
    echo "\n";
    echo $res;
    echo "\n";

    }
```

However, in the array, the links are stored in [link], the title of the link in [title] and the description in [description]. But i don't know how i would cope with adding $res to my array and to only use if the if statement works.

```
$output = Array();

   foreach ($links as $thisLink) {
   $output[] = array("link" => $thisLink, "title" => Titles($thisLink), "description" => getMetas($thisLink), getMetas($res));
     } 
    print_r($output);
```

Comment: not sure of the construction of your variables/arrays, but when you are in the `if` block, why not just insert the contents of `$res` into the array at the time of detection?  Where is the link, titles and meta data stored... in an assoc array?  object?

Comment: where are you setting the `$links` ? show the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_push() to add $res back to your array and then evaluate the array however you need to; not 100% sure what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

From your wording I think you want to do this:

```
$outputs = array();

foreach ($links as $thisLink) {
    $output = array("link" => $thisLink, "title" => Titles($thisLink), "description" => getMetas($thisLink));

    if ($output['description'] == null) {
        $output['description'] = getMetas($res);
    }

    $outputs[] = $output;
}
```

You might want to adjust the if statement because I do not know what getMetas() returns when there is not description.

Comment: Oh, I missed a character. Now it accumulates the links in the $outputs variable. Please check $outputs with var_dump.